# Patterns in diffraction gratings

Tags: optics, visible-light, waves, diffraction

I have an image attached that displays diffraction gratings and chromatic dispersion. I’m curious why it has this sort of star shape. Also, if there is some sort of formula or way to predict the shape. Info on the pic: This is a photograph taken on my iPhone, with flash on, of my tv.[image]